# Too many associations, aggregations or compositions in a class diagram?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, astah

We're tasked to make a system that will record students daily in and out of the institution premises via student ID, to ensure student safety, and The instructor can also use this system as the student attendance.

Can you help me by checking if this is correct or any improvement is required?

[image]

Comment: The answer is neither no nor yes and thus can not be given. Please be more specific in your question. Reviews are not the right place here at SO.

Comment: Indeed,  as @qwerty_so explained, SO is not the best pace for reviews.  I nevertheless answered it as it raised some interesting points regarding associations. I suggest to change the title so that it will be useful for others having hesitations.  In principle for a programming language we expect an explanation of the expected result and why it doesn't work.  For your future UML questions, we would therefore expect that you explain why you chose some UML elements  (expectations) and why you have doubts.

Answer (score 1):

### In short

There are some syntactic issues with the associations in your diagram.

Moreover, associations correspond to a structural relationship. Do not create associations, simply because one class uses another at some point in time: for a simple use, a `«use»` dependency is the most you can do.

### More details

Syntactically, this diagram seems correct, except for the label on the association:

- Since it's in the middle of the line, we assume it's the association name.  But the association name has no visibility.
- Since there is a `-` (private) visibility, we understand that it could be the role of an association end.  But It should then be located on the end and not in the middle.

Semantically, from an UML point of view there are some suspicious relationships:

- The double composition of `Login` is probably wrong: composition indicates an exclusive ownership.  Your diagram says that a `Login` occurence is owned either by an Admin or by a Teacher but if it's owned by one, the other cannot be related to it.
- Moreover, composition suggest a part-whole relationship and I don't see a login to "be a part of" a teacher or an admin.
- The aggregation is not well defined in UML and therfore does not really add value.  Some people see it suggesting a part§whole relation with non-exclusive ownership: in this case it would be wrong.  Better get rid of it.
- The name of the `Validates` association is confusing as it corresponds to a `Login`'s operation. It might lead to think that the line corresponds to the dynamic invocation of the operation, whereas in reality an association is structural.

But it's difficult to say more in absence of any requirement or analysis context. Based on my domain knowledge:

- The 1 to 1 association between `Admin` and `Student` must be wrong,  since an `Admin` may enrol 0 users (new admin), or many users
- There's a login which is probably used to monitor the in's of the students, but nothing seems to monitor the outs.
- Do each student have only one single teacher ?
- It's not clear to me if all these associations are a structural relation.  For example, we can understand that at a point in time, in a transaction, a teacher validates a login.  But should a trace of this validation be kept (i.e.  do you expect to be able to later find out all the logins that a teacher has validated?  or to find for a given login which teacher did validate it?).

Comment: The dbl-composition is definitely wrong since an object can be only composite aggregated to one class.

Comment: @qwerty_so That was initial reaction. But recently someone drew my attention at the wording of the specs being about individual objects and not about classes: “requires that a part object is included in at most one composite object at a time” (p.110) This wording allows to have different objects of the same class being part of different composites of different classes, and this is why I was less categoric. I couldn’t fond any prohibition of such structure. Nevertheless in my experience, 99% of the double-compositions are wrong and based on misunderstandings. And I bet it’s wrong here as well.

Comment: I guess you're right. Now I remember that too. In any case, composition isn't used correctly in many (or rather most) cases. That's why I say: don't use it unless you exactly know why and for what purpose.